# how to get the value of input box in the same view page before clicking on submit?

Tags: php, codeigniter

good evening all..
i have one question which belongs to php-codeigniter forms.
i have a form in my view page as follows:

```
echo form_open('someaction');
echo form_input('some_name',$some_value);
// here i want get the value before submitting.
echo form_submit('submit','submit');
echo form_close();
```

i want to get the value of that input box in the same view page before clicking on submit.
i dont have any controller and model.
only the  form i have that i mentioned above.

Comment: use javascript or jquery, and submit the form using js, before submitting you can get the value of textbox using its id

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to do that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var val = document.getElementById('id_here');
    // .... you can do anything with the value now
</script>
```

Comment: hi by above code i am always getting a null value in the alert.

Comment: but i am not getting the mentioned id value

Comment: Try to put the code after the form. or use jQuery
 `<script> $(document).ready(function(){ here the code }); </script>`